# How to make and use LESS templates?

Tags: css, less

I want to get a general idea of how to make and use LESS templates. I'm guessing a template should consist of css rules which makes use of less @variables, and when you simply @import that template into another .less file that contains defined variables... Is that it? Any examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you're right! Look at the doc here : http://lesscss.org/#-importing

Then you can find some collections of pre coded [mixins](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins) you'll be able to reuse by importing them, here is an exemple : http://lesselements.com/

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the less file structure of Bootstrap 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

that is a better example